# Connection pool and File handles

Tags: threadpool, file-descriptor, okhttp, filehandle

We use Retrofit/OkHttp3 for all network traffic from our Android application. So far everything seems to run quite smoothly.

However, we have now occasionally had our app/process run out of file handles.

- Android allows for a max of 1024 file handles per process
- OkHttp will create a new thread for each async call
- Each thread created this way will (from our observation) be responsible for 3 new file handles (2 pipes and one socket).

> We were able to debug this exactly, where each dispached async call using `.enqueue()` will lead to an increase of open file handles of 3.

The problem is, that the [`ConnectionPool`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.html) in OkHttp seems to be keeping the connection threads around for much longer than they are actually needed. ([This post](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2636) talks of five minutes, though I haven't seen this specified anywhere.)

- That means if you are quickly dispatching request, the **connection pool will grow in size**, and so will the **number of file handles** - until you reach 1024 where the app crashes.

I've seen that it is possible to limit the number of parallel calls with [`Dispatcher.setMaxRequests()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Dispatcher.html)(although it seems unclear whether this actually works, see [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1936)) - but that still doesn't quite address the issue with the open threads and file handles piling up.

**How could we prevent OkHttp from creating too many file handles?**

Answer (score 8):

*I am answering my own question here to document this issue we had. It took us a while to figure this out and I think others might encounter this too and might be glad for this answer.*

---

Our **problem** was that we created one `OkHttpClient` *per request*, as we used it's builder/interceptor API to configure some per-request parameters like HTTP headers or timeouts.

By default each `OkHttpClient` comes with its own connection pool, which of course blows up the number of connections/threads/file handles and prevents proper reuse in the pool.

### Our solution

We solved the problem by manually creating a global `ConnectionPool` in a singleton, and then passing that to the `OkHttpClient.Builder` object which builds the actual `OkHttpClient`.

- This still allows for per-request configuration using the `OkHttpClient.Builder`
- Makes sure all `OkHttpClient` instances are still using a common connection pool.

We were then able to properly size the global connection pool.